# Layout grid with Wrap

Tags: layout, flutter, dart

is there some widget for grid use-case?

I am trying using Wrap with Expanded or Flexible inside it. Its not working.

Because I have dynamic widgets with random grid settings and need to draw like cols in css bootstrap.

```
Wrap(
children<Widget>:
[
  Expanded(flex: 2, child: ...)
  Expanded(flex: 4, child: ...)
]
)
```

Comment: could you provide an image of what you're trying to achieve? it is not clear right now.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: yes, staggered grid is cool, but it has own overflow inside it. when you put staggered grid inside singleChildScrollView and you want scroll down and tap inside the grid, you cant scrolling down because staggeredGrid has an own scrollView.